# AngularJS - Radio button not checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

I have an `ng-repeat` with a bunch of radio buttons inside:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="offer in vm.offerList">
    ...    
    <td ng-show="offer.edit">
        <div class="row">                        
            <input type="radio" name="before" ng-model="offer.before" value="false">
            <input type="radio" name="before" ng-model="offer.before" value="true">
       </div>
   </td>
   ...
</div>
```

The model `offer.before` has the correct value, however, when the row is shown, the radio button doesn't appear checked. Why is this happening? I need the radio button to show the selected value.

This is a fiddle example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/danielrvt/dpoLdgjq/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because anything inside attribute `value` gets `toString()` like value `true` will be considered as `'true'` & it will looks for `'true'`(string) instead of `true`(boolean).

Better use `ng-value` instead of `value` attribute. It will treat `true` value as in `true` of type boolean only.

Additionally in your case you have to add `name` attribute to be unique for each radio button group each `offer` element radio will be considered as unique form element.

**Markup**

```
<div class="row">
    {{offer.before}}
    <input type="radio" name="before{{$index}}" ng-model="offer.before" ng-value="false">
    <input type="radio" name="before{{$index}}" ng-model="offer.before" ng-value="true">
</div>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ccf8rntL/)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I updated answer with OP's fiddle.. Though thanks for heads up :)

Comment: Why for example is this working perfectly but it doesn’t when the type=‘radio’ ??? <input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>

Comment: Can you please share a fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLX33M4EPJAC

Comment: What is the issue, I tried it, but can not figure what issue you're facing. Can you please elaborate more on it?
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLX41P26BSR2

Comment: The issue is that when it’s a checkbox, it respects the default values and starts off with the checkbox set (‘checkStatus’ model variable is “true” as expected after ng-init). And then you can continuously toggle it off and on. However if you set the type to be ‘radio’ instead of ‘checkbox’ it starts out with the radio button NOT set initially and you can only toggle it on once and then it is stuck, because the ‘checkStatus’ model variable seems to have not been set and is ‘false’ (0) by default. I was expecting both variants (checkbox vs. radio) showing identical behavior, but they are not...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLX6EENNJ37X —> type set to “radio”

Comment: @mramosch First of all, this has nothing to do with AngularJS, I think you have misunderstood the radio vs checkbox mechanism, basically checkbox have by default `true/false` value, but for `radio` you have to explicitly define the value... here you just set value for `ng-model` without defining radio element value..
Providing value to each radio box, should solve this desire behavior

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GLX6K8G1UAVJ

Comment: I know about the principal mechanism of radio-buttons, but nevertheless I would like to achieve the same behavior a checkbox has, but with ONE single radio-button, because the visual design of a checkbox doesn’t fit in my UI at all. Therefore I wanna use a radio-button, who‘s appearance is much more pleasing in my situation. Thanks for helping BTW ;-) Appreciate that..

Comment: You can change the checkbox css to appear like radio, but you can't alter the behavior.

Comment: So there is no way to toggle the state of a single radio button back and forth? And there is no way to get the value of the buttons current on/off status?